# iPhone keyboard-button style for any UIView / UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, keyboard

I have a custom keyboard in my app and I'd like to have it look similar to the original iPhone keyboard (especially the buttons), just like it has been realized in Twitterrific, for example. Can you point me to a resource where I could find such code, either as a custom `drawRect` method or as a `TTStyle` pipeline?

Cheers

MrMage

Answer (score 0):

For the drawRect method you could easily take a screenshot and get the button image from there.

Comment: I need dynamic size buttons and I'd like to have a real drawRect method for easier customization.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do your own custom drawing for the keys.  One way to do this would be to use the excellent tool [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/) to draw up the keys, based on a screenshot you took of the iPhone keyboard.  Opacity can output the code for a UIView subclass containing all of the Quartz custom drawing code (in the UIView's -drawRect:) for creating your custom view.